# Google Analytics Event Tracking on Page Exit

Tags: javascript, events, google-analytics, analytics, tracking

I have a javscript code wich record visitors interaction with the website (like calculating max scroll position, mouse movement in pixels, etc). However, these statistics are valid, only if the user stops interacting with the page. (he leaves, clicks a link, closes the browser, etc)

Is it possible to do a _gaq_push when this happens? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work.

```
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = storeData;
    function storeData(){
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Visitor Info', 'Scrolling', 'Up', 200, true]);
    }
</script>
```

However, it's worth noting by pushing an event to Google Analytics, it affects bounce rate calculation, which in your case would cause it to appear that users never bounced. So you [must include that last parameter](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html#SettingUpEventTracking), and set it to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding your push calls to the [window.onunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload) event?