# Google Analytics Event Tracking - Page Exit

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, jquery-events

I'm trying to track when a user exits the page using the code below but it doesn't seem to be firing the event:

```
function storeData(){

            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Application Form', 'exit-form_application_', 4, '', false]);
        }
$(window).on('unload',storeData);
```

I've also tried other ways such as the method shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866666/google-analytics-event-tracking-on-page-exit) but I still can't get it to fire. I have other events which are firing successfully e.g when a form field is completed/skipped but can't seem to get this one to work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is not firing at all or is just not registering the event? If last, then maybe order of your variables is wrong I think. Value needs to be a number. Maybe this will work better?

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Application Form', 'exit-form_application_', '', 4, false]);
```

Comment: I've got another question actually which I've asked here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16565433/google-analytics-track-event-on-page-exit-except-form-submission if you can help? Thanks