# Google Analytics - Track Event on Page Exit (Except form submission)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, tracking, event-tracking

I'm using the following code to track when a user exits a page on my site:

```
//track on page exit
function storeData(){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Application Form', 'exit-form_application_', '', 4, false]);
}
$(window).on('unload',storeData);
```

However, I don't want to trigger the event when the form is submitted, therefore how could I prevent this?

Comment: You could use a flag (global variable)

Comment: Sorry can you please expand? DO you mean something like var track = true; and add if(track == true) around the _gaq.push? Then on submit of the form set the track variable to false?

Comment: Ya, exactly, this is the simplest way to do it

Comment: OK, I've thought of another way, see my initial question...

Comment: If your update works, its all good

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
           _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Application Form', 'exit-form_application_', '', 4, false]);
        });

        $("#formID").submit(function(){
            $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
        });
```

Comment: does the call to Google always finish in time, though? before the new page is loaded? Does it correctly register this event?

Comment: no - if the page is unloaded for an outbound link, GA may not have sent the event.  You need to use hitcallback as described here: [Use Google Analytics hitCallback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086587/track-event-in-google-analytics-upon-clicking-form-submit/12461558#12461558). @Mansiemans