# How do creating a Google Analytics Event Tracking to record what form field last had focus before a visitor exited the website

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a number of client websites that all have forms such as contact us OR book an appointment OR sign up for a newsletter.

According to my Google Analytics page, these pages are often the most frequent exit page on each respective website so I would like to record which form field last had focus before a visitor left the website.

I am familiar with Google Analytics Event Tracking, however, it's the form field focus part of this problem which I cannot understand.

I have found a similar answer here: [Google Analytics Event Tracking on Page Exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866666/google-analytics-event-tracking-on-page-exit) but that doesn't discuss form field focus.

What is my best approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a custom variable instead ? You can attach an event handler to a onFocus or onChange event and store the last used form field there - if the visitor jumps to the next field you overwrite the last value with the name of the current form field. The advantage (in my opinion) over event tracking is that you do not need to store a lot of unnecessary events (because you're really interested in the last field the visitors clicked on, while event tracking would store any field anybody has ever clicked).

Assuming you have jquery and a form with the css id of "contact" you could do something like the following (untested, might need tweaking, should be executed after the form is display or wrapped in a document.ready-call):

```
$('#contact input').on('focus', function() {
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
          1,                   // Slot 1 of five
          'Contact form',      // The name of the form
          $(this).attr('name'),               // The name of the form field
          2                    // Sets the scope to session-level.  Optional parameter.
       ]);  
    }
});
```

(Technical details for custom vars are here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables).

You would use this value to create custom segments in Analytics ("display all visits to the contact form where the value of the custom var equals the name of the third (fourth, n-th) form field") to show you all visitors that have gotten to a certain field in the form but no further.